# better way of doing this SELECT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, join

Best way to do this SELECT?

I've got this tables:

**t_department**
id
name

**t_users**
id
name
type

*type can be:
1 SuperUser
2 normalUser

**t_department_superuser** 
(A department can have many superUsers)

-idSuperUser
-idDepartment

**t_superuser_normaluser**
(A superUser can have many normalusers)

-idSuperUser
-idNormalUser

and finally

**t_actions**

-id (autonumeric)
-idUser (this can be an id of superUser or normalUser)
-action

Given a department name, for example "mainDepartment"
I need to get all records from t_actions of all normalusers and all superusers of that department

I have this, it works, but I am not an SQL expert (I am using MySQL) and I think it is not the best way to do the select, and t_actions is going to have loads of rows:

```
SELECT id,idUser,action
FROM t_actions
WHERE (idUser IN (

SELECT DISTINCT t_department_superuser.idSuperUser FROM t_department
RIGHT JOIN t_department_superuser ON t_department_superuser.idDepartment = t_department.id
LEFT JOIN t_superuser_normaluser ON t_superuser_normaluser.idSuperUser = t_department_superuser.idSuperUser
WHERE name='mainDepartment'


UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT t_superuser_normaluser.idNormalUser
FROM t_department
RIGHT JOIN t_department_superuser ON t_department_superuser.idDepartment = t_department.id
LEFT JOIN t_superuser_normaluser ON t_superuser_normaluser.idSuperUser = t_department_superuser.idSuperUser
WHERE name='mainDepartment') 

ORDER BY id;
```

Any suggestions to make this better? thank you!!

Comment: Paging would always be the starting point. do you need to select every record at once, ex: this is a report going into a spreadsheet, or can you page the record, by selecting only the first 10 users and all their changes.

Comment: At first we are looking for a SELECT of everything. Because there is another field in table t_actions that is the date of the action. And the clients will not request for everything in the table, only the rows depending on the timediff. We will do a timediff. But there are going to be a lot of rows in t_action, and there are going to be like 50 superusers, with thousands of normalusers each one.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you are using left and right joins there will be null records, which is why you need the UNION... you can cut out the UNION with a simple null check

```
SELECT id, idUser, action
FROM t_actions
WHERE idUser IN
(   SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(tsn.idNormalUser, tds.idSuperUser)
    FROM t_department td
    RIGHT JOIN t_department_superuser tds ON tds.idDepartment = td.id
    LEFT JOIN t_superuser_normaluser tsn ON tsn.idSuperUser = tds.idSuperUser
    WHERE td.name='mainDepartment'
)
ORDER BY id;
```

note i also added alias's to your table names so its easer to write out and read the columns you are trying to select and join on.

EDIT

with the data the only possible way to do it with this table design is like this

```
SELECT id, idUser, action
FROM t_actions
WHERE idUser IN
((SELECT tds.idSuperUser
  FROM t_department td
  JOIN t_department_superusers tds ON tds.idDepartment = td.id
  WHERE td.name='MAIN')

 UNION
 (SELECT tsn.idNormalUser
  FROM t_department td
  JOIN t_department_superusers tds ON tds.idDepartment = td.id
  JOIN t_superuser_normaluser tsn ON tsn.idSuperUser = tds.idSuperUser
  WHERE td.name='MAIN')
)
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked and made my SELECT smaller and much cleaner with the alias, if anyone has any more ideas to improve this SELECT (if it is possible) it would be great.

Comment: @user3032175 sure thing! glad I could help. did it speed up your query? if you want more help i'd need you to post a sqlfiddle with some sample relevant data so I can test it

Comment: I've got a problem with the SELECT inside the IN. It only returns me the normalUsers, but not the SuperUsers. If I change the order of:SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(tds.idSuperUser,tsn.idNormalUser) it returns me the superusers. but never returns me superusers and normalusers. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @user3032175 can you post some data in your question? you may need to change the right join to a left join.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that a superUSer can be in many departments?

Comment: @user3032175 no that shouldn't matter. its probably because there are no nulls from the right join. try running the inner select without the coalesce and see whats returned.. `SELECT DISTINCT tsn.idNormalUser, tds.idSuperUser FROM... `

Comment: Without the COALESCE I get the whole list of links between normalusers and superusers, from that department. With no nulls. The list is correct.

Comment: @user3032175 you dont want a list of links though for this query since its a subquery. you want either normalusers or superusers right? so try changing the RIGHT JOIN to a LEFT JOIN and join both by department

Comment: I want all the super users and normal users of one department, in one column (I don't know if it is possible)

Comment: @user3032175 POST SOME DATA! I can't help without being able to manipulate it myself. if you tried what I recommended and that doesn't work then you will have to post some data.